# Camel text file to sql-developer transfer hello world

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm reading the doc about Apache Camel and I still don't get how to transfer the data of the text file to the sql developer schema. 
I feel like this part is what confuses me the most:

```
from("file:/tmp/input?move=./done")
        .process(new MyLogProcessor())
        .bean(new MyTransformer(), "TransformContent")
        // write it to this output
        .to("sql:select * from articles where category = #"");
```

Is there any hello world app to transfer from a text file to the sql dev that I can see to get an idea of how things work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You must `transform` the output of the file to a String. Something like:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:/tmp/input?move=./done")
    .log("order content: ${body}")
    .transform(new Expression() {

        @Override
        public <T> T evaluate(Exchange exchange, Class<T> type) {
            String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            return (T) body;
        }

    })
    .to("sql:select * from articles where category = #?dataSource=myDS")
    .log("query content: ${body}");
}
```

I've added some log to see how the result of each step is performing.

Comment: thanks for the hint, how do you append the data from the text file to the database? Those that happen in that select line?

Comment: As there is one unique parameter, Camel make automatically the matching, converting the only one found. If you need to provide more parameters you may need to have a look at "using named parameter" at the component documentation: https://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html

Comment: In your example, you may reference `#field1` and `#field2` and provide an expression that return a `Map<String,String>` mapping values to those keys, according the content provided in your body (your file content in this case). Camel will take care to get those values from the map and inject into the underlying JDBC prepared statement.

Comment: Expression is not needed IMHO. You can convert file InputStream to String with just `from("file:xxx").convertBodyTo(String.class)`

Comment: Probably he will finally need to do some parsing on the content and provide a map with useful values, I guess it's the typical use case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you need to parse the content of the file to the SQL, but you need to convert the body to String:

```
from("file:/tmp/input?move=./done")
        .process(new MyLogProcessor())

        ... What ever you want here

        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("sql:select * from articles where category = #"");
```